# Type of noun- If it is not a feeling/state/ action

Tags: abstract-nouns

I have word

> situation

Is this an abstract noun? I don't think it's an abstract noun as it does not describe a feeling, state or action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concrete vs Abstract nouns](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/concrete-vs-abstract-nouns)

Comment: It's difficult to define the exact difference between an *abstract* and a *concrete* noun.  To me it seems many nouns "sit on the fence", so to speak, and "situation" is one of them.  There are some situations I can sense, and some I can only think about. Fortunately, unless you are a professional linguist, it rarely matters.

Comment: lol i had an exam so it matters for me. i think it is not abstract

Comment: In my opinion, when something like this is on an exam, the only way to get the answer correct is to accurately guess what your teacher *thinks* is the correct answer -- by which I mean I think it's a stupid question.   If it was my test, I would mark you correct if you can argue, in English, which you think it is and why.   You did this, so I think you've demonstrated a far more useful English skill than some mostly pointless distinction between two different flavors of noun.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the reply. The exam was at a national level and its checked by a computerized system. Anyways, I just wanted to know so i could be careful of this mistake for the future.Also i wanted to know what a native english speaker would do.

Comment: Most native speakers would not have a clue what is the difference between an abstract or a concrete noun, nor would they care.  It's simply not important to 99.999% of communication.  Like me, they'd have to guess.  Again, at the risk of sounding rude, when "educators" put stuff like that on a national test, its only possible purpose is to reward those who have studied every possible trivial "rule" and have learned to think as they have been taught to think.  It promotes a certain limited kind of scholarship, not English ability.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your help and time. The education system just sucks. i also personally think that knowing these things is of no use as long as you know how to speak English properly. :)

Comment: feeling, state or action sounds like the description of a verb, not a noun....

Answer (score 1):

There is no grammatical classification of nouns as "concrete" or "abstract".

When learning nouns we are told that "nouns name things", but not just concrete things like "dog", "cheese" but also abstract things like "love" or "temptation". This is just to remind you that nouns can also be abstract.

But this is a category of meaning, not grammar. Many words can have both concrete and abstract senses, and some senses can have aspects of both concrete and abstract meanings.  For example "love" is an abstract noun when we say "My love for you grows stronger every day."  But it is a concrete noun (meaning "girlfiend") when we say "Come to me, my love!"

So is the *meaning* of "situation" abstract or concrete. That could depend on the sentence that you use it in.  In most sentences it would have an abstract meaning, as it wouldn't name a physical thing, instead it means "how things are" which is an abstract quality.

Comment: ab·stract noun
noun
plural noun: abstract nouns
a noun denoting an idea, quality, or state rather than a concrete object.
"the website contains considerably more abstract nouns than hard facts" Oxford Languages

Comment: What's your point?  Yes  there is a dictionary definition of "abstract noun".  No, it is not a grammatical category in English.   Contrast this to "masculine noun in French"  It is the opposite. The gender of a word carries little or no meaning - it is purely a grammatical property of words.  This is the exact opposite.  Whether a noun is concrete or abstract is purely a semantic matter and translingual.

Comment: "There is no grammatical classification of nouns as "concrete" or "abstract"." Yes, but there is a classification of them as abstract. Grammar is not relevant here. Words like wealthy, beauty, ugliness, are abstract.

Comment: That is entirely translingual, you could equally say richesse, beauté, laideur or 财富、美丽、丑陋  So the question of "is a noun abstract" is not actually a question of English.

Comment: I fail to see your point. And it is totally about English because abstract nouns when being used notionally take no determiners: Understanding wealth can be useful. Understanding the wealth generated here can be useful. French always has to have a determiner.

Comment: No, abstract nouns take deteminers  "His beauty is beyond compare"  The category of words that can take a "zero" determiner is the uncountable nouns, and that *is* a grammatical category.  But many uncountable nouns have concrete meanings (like cheese).  So take care.  Word can have more or less abstract meaning, but that is a property of the meaning, not a property of the word.

Comment: And furthermore "situation" has an abstract meaning, yet it is countable.

Comment: Which is what my answer is about.  The *meaning* of the word situation is normally abstract. But it doesn't make sense to ask if the "situation" is abstract, if by "is abstract" you mean "belongs to a particular word class in English grammar", since there is no such word class in English gramamr.

Comment: You are not reading what I say: I said when the abstract word involves the notion (beauty versus the notion of beauty), no determiner is used. Like this:  Understanding wealth can be useful. Understanding the wealth generated here can be useful. So, I repeat, when using the abstract noun as a notion, no determiner is used. **His beauty is beyond compare.** versus **Beauty is in the eye of the beholder**. There is a major difference between those uses. It is not about count versus non-count.

Comment: But under any reasonable definition of "abstract" the meaning of the word "beauty" in "His beauty is beyond compare" is abstract, not concrete.  I don't disagree with much of what you say, I just think it to be irrelevant. It's not about count or non-count, or even about different meanings of "beauty".  The question is "is situation an abstract noun". And my answer is and remains:  "Whether the meaning of "situation" is abstract or concrete could depend on the sentence that you use it in. In most sentences it would have an abstract meaning, as it wouldn't name a physical thing."

Comment: James, you don't get it: His beauty is not discussing the notion of beauty but rather HIS beauty. Whereas: Beauty is in the eyes of the beholder. is the notion.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't get the point you are making.

Comment: Well, you let me repeat it three times without saying anything. What I am saying accounts for why in English these types of nouns can be used without determiners.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your definition for "abstract noun" as describing "a feeling,state or action"? My understanding of "abstract noun" is a little more inclusive, in fact, basically, it's any noun that isn't "concrete".

[Yourdictionary.com](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-abstract-nouns.html) adds a few more categories to the ones you specify:

> Concrete nouns are tangible and you can experience them with your five senses. Abstract nouns refer to intangible things, like actions, feelings, ideals, concepts and qualities.

According to them, "situation" would be abstract because it is an intangible concept.

I do tend to agree with Andrew though, in that it doesn't make too much practical difference whether a noun is abstract or not.

Comment: From internet,school etc i know that abstract is something that we cannot feel by our 5 senses. But i think a situation is something which we can actually sense